# Sed: unescaped newline inside substitute pattern

Tags: sed

I want to replace '-Djava.library.path=""' with '-Djava.library.path="path"' in file named "file" using sed

```
sed -i 's/-Djava.library.path=""/-Djava.library.path="path"/g' -f file
```

returns

```
sed: 2: file: unescaped newline inside substitute pattern
```

What's wrong? Can someone help?

Comment: Try removing `-f` as  this is for appending more sed commands rather than introducing the input file i.e. `sed -i 's/-Djava.library.path=""/-Djava.library.path="path"/g' file` is suffice. N.B. the `.` in the LHS of the regexp denotes any character and perhaps should be escaped.

Comment: sed -i 's/-Djava\.library\.path=""/-Djava\.library\.path="path"/g' file
Returns:
sed: 1: "file": invalid command code f

sed -i 's/-Djava\.library\.path=""/-Djava\.library\.path="path"/g' -f file
Returns 
sed: 2: file: unescaped newline inside substitute pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed to

```
sed -i 's/Djava.library.path=""/Djava.library.path="path"/' file
```

Now it works.